# "Unexpected end of input" using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, json, row

I am building a thread-messaging system. I used AJAX to send the parent_id to the php file which retrieved the thread (many messages with the same parent_id)

in the ajax, I send the parent_id

```
data:{
    parent_id: $(this).data('id'),
    ajax: 'true'
},
```

I use this parent_id in the php file using a query which retrieves some rows and I pass them back using this :

```
$ret_msg_query_result=mysql_query($retrive_query);
while ($retrieved_msg_fetched=mysql_fetch_assoc($ret_msg_query_result))
{
echo json_encode($retrieved_msg_fetched) . "\n";    
}
```

and then back to Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".msgsRow li.msg_subject,.msgsRow li.msg_content").click(function() { 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST',
            url: AJAX_URL+"front/RetrieveMsg.php", 
            data:{ parent_id: $(this).data('id'), ajax: 'true' }, 
            success: function(data) { 
                         var strLines = data.split("\n"); 
                         for (var i in strLines) { 
                             var obj = JSON.parse(strLines[i]); 
                             console.log(obj.id); 
                         }
                     } 
            }); 
        }); 
     });
```

I got this way (of splitting) to convert each row into an object from a post here on Stackoverflow [Sending/Parsing multiple JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209527/sending-parsing-multiple-json-objects)

The function works right retrieving the ids of messages and even retrieving the full row. But I get

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input "

and it points to the line before console.log(obj.id);

I searched StackOverflow for this error and it usually appears for missing a closing parenthesis but I can'd find any.

Thanks,

Comment: How does the data that you're recieving look like?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `}` on in this function

```
success: function(data){
                var strLines = data.split("\n");
                for (var i in strLines) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(strLines[i]);
                    console.log(obj.id);
                **}**
            }
```

NOTE: remove the 4x*, those should not be there :)

That should fix it!

Comment: Well, Thanks limelights but I already have this in my code, I am sorry that I didn't paste all the code but here it is

$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".msgsRow li.msg_subject,.msgsRow li.msg_content").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: AJAX_URL+"front/RetrieveMsg.php",
   data:{
    parent_id: $(this).data('id'),
    ajax: 'true'
   },
   success: function(data){
    var strLines = data.split("\n");
    for (var i in strLines) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(strLines[i]);
      console.log(obj.id);
     }
    }
   });
  })
 })

Comment: All right, I'll edit your question with the correct code then.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem ... It's because I am splitting using "/n" which makes the strLines be something like {row},{row},{row},

The comma in the end causes the unexpected end. So, I used a counter to check the number of row, if it's the last, then don't insert "/n"

```
$counter=1;

while ($retrieved_msg_fetched=mysql_fetch_assoc($ret_msg_query_result))
{
    if ($counter==mysql_num_rows($ret_msg_query_result))
    {
    echo json_encode($retrieved_msg_fetched);
    }
    else{
    echo json_encode($retrieved_msg_fetched) . "\n";
    $counter++;
    }   
}
```

Thanks Limelights for your help too :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I forgot to return something from my php-script when it worked fine. I just added something like this:

```
die (json_encode (array ('reponse'=>'Your script worked fine')));
```

at the end of my php-script, and that solved it. You can also use 'response' to check it it worked fine.