# Parse JSON file containing multiple objects

Tags: json, node.js

I have a JSON file that contains multiple objects of the same structure that look like this:

```
{
   "id": "123",
   "type": "alpha"
}
{
   "id": "321",
   "type": "beta"
}
```

I'm using node.js to read the file.

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + "/filename.json", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
var content = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

If I do a console.log(content) things look good.  I see the content of the json file.  I'm trying to iterate over each object but I'm not sure how to do that.  I've tried using

```
for(var doc in content)
```

but the doc isn't each object as I was expecting.  How do I loop over the content to get each object in a json format so that I can parse it?

Comment: I don t think your JSON syntax is good, are you sure it s the real file and JSON.parse doesn t throw up any error?

Comment: It's not valid JSON, but it is a common JSON streaming format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending/Parsing multiple JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209527/sending-parsing-multiple-json-objects)

Answer (score 1):

If `content` is an array, you can use

```
content.forEach(function (obj, index) { /* your code */ })
```

See documentation for [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

if you need to just iterate, a forEach loop would work or a normal for loop :

```
for(var i = 0; i<content.length(); i++){
//perform whatever you need on the following object
var myobject  = content[i];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Depend of the files, the two current answer (Osama and Daniel) assume you have a JSON Array:

```
[
    {
        "id": "123",
        "type": "alpha"
    },
    {
        "id": "456",
        "type": "beta"
    }
]
```

In which case, you can use any array iterator:

```
var async = require('async'),
    content = require(__dirname + "/filename.json");
async.each(content, function (item, callback) {
    //...
});
```

But in your case, it seems to not be JSON (no bracket to indicate array, and no comma to separate the objects), so in the case `JSON.parse` doesn t throw up any error, you'll need to isolate your objects first:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    async = require('async');

fs.readFile(__dirname + "/filename.notjson", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    var content = data.split('}');
    async.map(content, function (item, callback) {
        callback(null, JSON.parse(item));
    }, function (err, content) {
        console.log(content);
    };
});
```

Comment: You don't need to use async library to loop through an array

Comment: @simon-p-r: sure, but it s late here, and I m not sure of the correct syntax for `array.map`/`forEach`, while with async I m sure the script is functionnal, if not optimal.

Comment: this goes to a direction what I'm looking for whan reading the title of the question. unfortunately, the solution which searches for `}` is too basic for most structures