# Convert JSON Output to C# List

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

I've some JSON data coming back as a string that looks like (copy and paste from VS text visualizer):

```
{
   "error":0,
   "result":{
      "name":"wjetestuser1",
      "id":"0eu0_User_2_0b4cfb616e648d4792056c1a6e7d801e_null",
      "status":"ACTIVE"
   }
}
{
   "match":[
      [
         "domain.id",
         "=",
         "2"
      ],
      [
         "loginName",
         "=",
         "wjetestuser1"
      ]
   ],
   "return":[
      "name",
      "id",
      "status"
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to turn this into a List for everything after the `"result":` and before `{"match":` without using a replace command, so I'll end up with a list that looks something like:

```
Name, wjetestuser1
id, 0eu0_User_2_0b4cfb616e648d4792056c1a6e7d801e_null
status, ACTIVE
```

If I can get the error code status back thats a bonus, but really not needed.

I'm hoping there is a simple one (or a few liners) that don't involve hacking the string apart with a replace regex command.

Various code attempts so far, but this worked for me if I strip before and including `"result":` and after and including `{"match":`

s below is the output above as a single line

```
s = commonCode.ExeApiCall(url);
var DSData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
var jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(s);
```

errors at the 3rd line down with error:

> Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: {. Path '', line 1, position 119.

Comment: There's a million JSON to C# questions on Stack Overflow, have you tried looking?

Comment: Yes.  And tried lots of them and they throw back errors each time as the input didn't match their format - hence the question

Comment: So why didn't you show us some of your effort? Because right now your question looks like "please write code for me" which we don't do here.

Comment: So why not ask a question about those errors then? (after doing some research)

Comment: Newtonsofts JSON parser is widely used and freely available. Use it to parse the string, then filter out the information you need.

Comment: why you have 2 root elements?

Comment: Oh yes, this is not valid JSON, good spot @alex.

Comment: @Alex, thats how the data is presented to me from a product called Dualshield

Comment: that position 119 from error message is the last parenthesis of the first root element. You have to split that string into two json objects. (i wonder if it is a bug in their API or they expect you to do extra work parsing string of multiple json objects).

Comment: [mildly relavant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209527/sending-parsing-multiple-json-objects)

Comment: I knew I had saw this before: From Json.NET documentation [Read Multiple Fragments With JsonReader](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sir Rufo pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45488543/convert-json-output-to-c-sharp-list#comment-78019665) if you use Newtownsoft library you can [Read Multiple Fragments With JsonReader](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm). Example from the website:

```
public class Role
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    string json = @"{ 'name': 'Admin' }{ 'name': 'Publisher' }";
    IList<Role> roles = new List<Role>();

    JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
    reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

    while (true)
    {
        if (!reader.Read())
            break;

        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        Role role = serializer.Deserialize<Role>(reader);
        roles.Add(role);
    }

    foreach (Role role in roles)
        Console.WriteLine(role.Name);
}
```

---

My original answer was making minimal JSON parser to this particular case scenario. [See revision history for that](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45489739/revisions#revc9b4f151-22e3-4de7-ae88-9ddc4abd14ff).

Comment: Thank you.  the top set of code worked straight off.  Second set, I put my string 's' between the brackets of .ToJsons(s) and it came out perfect.
This was a lot tidier than the regex mess I was working with.

Comment: @WayneEvans fyi friend: it's impossible to solve it with regex. you have to use stack. [some reference to study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)

Comment: Try your extension method with this **valid** JSON string *{"foo}{5":"bar}{6"}*

Comment: @alex You have to write a (nearly) complete json parser to split the root elements, which can be an object or an array as well. If you are going to write one, I can give you some JSON examples for the unit tests :o)

Comment: @alex No need to implement a feature already implemented by Json.NET (see my last comment at the question)